# How do I edit CSS in Chrome like in Firebug for Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've been editing CSS using Firebug in Firefox, but recently noticed that Chrome is rendering my pages much quicker (with scrolling, interactive elements etc) and wanted to switch to it.

I found Chrome shows the computed CSS and what attributes are overruled in the stack and I can alter them one-by-one but what I liked about Firebug was that I could just edit the entire stylesheet in a real-time text editor. Is this same feature somewhere in the Chrome developer panel, or is there a Chrome extension that lets me alter the stylesheets this way?

Comment: welcome to the hordes of developers waiting for this feature in chrome so we can all make a permanent switch to chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha). It can also save edited CSS.

Comment: Really helpful. I tried several extensions for chrome and I used this too. Believe me this is the best extension i found to edit style sheets in chrome. All other extensions doesn't allow you to edit local style sheets. Also the Famous FireBug is horrible extension for chrome.

Comment: i cant seem to get it working under mac... anyone an idea why?

Comment: Where in StyleBot can you see the entire stylesheet to add/edit rules?

Answer (score 10):

In current versions of Chrome (I'm running 16) you don't need any external add-ons. 
Right click anywhere in your page, choose **inspect element**, then in the window that shows up click the **Resources tab**, then in the left panel select the stylesheet you want to edit.  To begin editing you need to first double click, over the css text.

Comment: This works, but is terrible. If you accidentally leave the page, all your edits are lost, and on the sites I have tried edititing, it is **horribly** slow. Like 300 baud slow.

Comment: It's true all edits are lost if you close the page - it happened to me a few times before getting used to it. I never encountered any performance issue, I'm working on an 3yr old regular machine. But I love not having to launch any 3rd party add-ons if I can do the job out of the box.

Comment: I found out the speed had something to do with the fact that I had base64 encoded png's in my css. Every single keypress would re-request that resource for some reason. So the 'Resources' list in chrome would get *huge*.  Not sure what was going on there. But editing other css files without base64 encoded pngs worked fine.

Comment: You can't directly edit the file, making this anything but awkward.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit any property or create a new property by double click on an entry or empty space in Elements panel's styles pane. There is no way to edit entire css file just as text at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I use live.js! As you edit your css file it shows you the results realtime in your browser without having to refresh. http://livejs.com/

I've spend countless hours testing almost every Chome extension i could find (including stylebot) to mimic the live CSS editing of Firebug in Firefox. None to date have that same workflow. Live.js is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Web Developer Toolbar extension's CSS->Edit CSS tool?

Comment: This is my FAVORITE way to author styles. I use WDT's "Edit CSS" feature in tandem with Firebug (to view markup) and it's the best. My only beef is WDT for Chrome is a sub 1.0 release and very buggy, so I'm left having to author in Firefox. Also, if you are using a CSS preprocessor, you really can't take advantage of in-browser authoring/editing tools much at this point. I actually just blogged about this very issue yesterday: http://blog.joelglovier.com/post/30395741197/browser-based-css-authoring-ftw

Answer (score 1):

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

Web Developer Toolbar for Chrome > CSS > Edit CSS

Answer (score 0):

there's a semi-working [firebug extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench?hl=en) but it's not exactly perfect yet.

Answer (score 0):

User [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). It's also available as an extension to Chrome.

Comment: I've tried Firebug Lite, it doesn't have a live CSS text editor, and displays a whole bunch of computed styles that aren't present in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Jason: When I started typing your answer weren't there. But before I pressed the submit button I decided to double check the URL :-P

Comment: @Tom: I just tried Firebug Lite and I found that I can modify the CSS live in Chrome - just like in Firefox. Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: It can alter the style live, but it doesn't have the stylesheet in a text editor like Firebug for Firefox. Entering each value into each field is a headache.

Comment: Dude Firebug lite is in beginning beginning for now. They still developing it. Current version doesn't allow to edit local style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this - [Live Stylesheets](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epfcdciapgkgjdjkmijgdekgfmocneid)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [LiveCSSEditor](http://www.livecsseditor.com) 4 years ago for exactly this reason. FireBug in Firefox would let me free-hand write CSS into the page, but nothing else in Chrome would.

I still use it today and have yet to find a better solution. It may work for you as well. :)