# How do I save in Visual Studio CSS that I edited in chrome?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ide, browser

**Preamble**

I was thinking that a lot of year ago the WYSIWYG revolution was lost in the development..

Now web developers write code in Visual Studio -> Debug it with a Web Browser -> Edit CSS inside the web browser -> go back to Visual Studio saving that modifies and tries again in the web browser.

This process is simply slow. Compare it with the prodctivity of Adobe Photoshop or 3D Studio Max.

**The question**

Is it possible to use the web browser as an HTML / CSS editor at least for the minor changement?

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783186/how-do-i-edit-css-in-chrome-like-in-firebug-for-firefox)

;

;

Sometimes I think programmer love coding so much to prevent a real abstract vision of their work final purpose.. the code should be a mean to reach something, not the final purpose..
3D Studio i.e. is very modular and reusable, without having to write any code.

Comment: You should look at Browser Link and Web Essentials.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit CSS in Chrome like in Firebug for Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783186/how-do-i-edit-css-in-chrome-like-in-firebug-for-firefox)

Comment: Sam - how does this related question not help you?  I found at least 2 answers as to how to save edited CSS from Chrome.  Did I miss part of your question during my review?

Comment: I don't agree with your preamble. It seems you are using Visual Studio as a plain text editor rather than a full fledged HTML/CSS/Javascript IDE.